Error in FIJI: File --> Import --> Image sequence --> virtual stack: Image width and height are <= 0
I am attempting to import an image sequence of 70 multichannel images (in .tif format) in order to use the grid collection/stitching function to produce one large image. However, when I import the folder one of the files (Nikon_40) gets an error stating the width and height are zero. Yet, I can open the file individually in FIJI with no error and the image info gives a non-zero height and width (1024). Can anyone inform me as to why I keep getting this error? I have checked the metadata several times and can not find a zero value.
I have tried opening the files one at a time, all of which open correctly, yet when I import as sequence it hits this error.
Below is the google drive to the file that opens normally (Nikon_01.tif) and the file with an issue (Nikon_40.tif)
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wMMpwhBon8ns8r0iVCzE28WpBQpddfyU?usp=sharing

"when I import the folder one of the files (Nikon_40) gets an error"; So how do you import the folder? Importing Nikon files requires BioFormat-importer and I see no option to let it import whole folders of images/stacks.

The original poster writes in the first sentence that the images are in .tif format (I have not downloaded the linked files (yet)). In this case, it should be possible to import the entire folder, shouldn't it?

At least for me, the provided TIF-stacks don't open in plain ImageJ.

Indeed, it is a bit puzzling. I'm able to open the images individually by drag-and-drop or the BioFormat importer. If I drag-and-drop the complete folder or use Import -> Image Sequence and activate the option "Open as separate images", I get the same error as the OP. However, if this option is deactivated both images are opened as one stack without any problems. With my own multi-channel images, import -> Image Sequence and in combination with "Open as separate images" works without any problems.

The problem might be the dimensions order of the exported .tif files. It is Channels (c) = 1 and Frames (t) = 3. The following ImageJ macro code using the BioFormats importer (instead of Import -> Image Sequence) works with the two example images:
run("Bio-Formats Macro Extensions");

currentDirectory = getDirectory("Choose a directory");

fileList = getFileList(currentDirectory);

for (file = 0; file < fileList.length; file++) {
        
    Ext.isThisType(currentDirectory + fileList[file], supportedFileFormat);
    
    if (supportedFileFormat=="true") {
        Ext.setId(currentDirectory + fileList[file]);
        Ext.getSeriesCount(seriesCount);
        
        for (series = 1; series <= seriesCount; series++) {
            //record the Bio-Formats importer with the setup you need if different from below and change accordingly
            run("Bio-Formats Importer", "open=[" + currentDirectory + fileList[file] + "] autoscale color_mode=Composite rois_import=[ROI manager] view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT swap_dimensions z_1=1 c_1=3 t_1=1 series_"+series);
            
        }
        
    }
}

